# how to alert, if there are more than 50 requests in 10 seconds from the same IP Address

Tags: node.js, security, express

I got IP address of client with this function:

```
function getClientIp(req) {
    var ipAddress;
    // The request may be forwarded from local web server.
    var forwardedIpsStr = req.header('x-forwarded-for'); 
    if (forwardedIpsStr) {
        // 'x-forwarded-for' header may return multiple IP addresses in
        // the format: "client IP, proxy 1 IP, proxy 2 IP" so take the
        // the first one
        var forwardedIps = forwardedIpsStr.split(',');
        ipAddress = forwardedIps[0];
    }
    if (!ipAddress) {
        // If request was not forwarded
        ipAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    }
    return ipAddress;
};
```

I have IP addresses who requested my webpages. What is the right way to show an alert to users who send requests more than 50 in 10 second?

I am using express framework.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-brute

You can use that package to set up various rate limits on your app. There are a bunch of code examples on that page.

Otherwise you'll have to do some work with sessions to keep track of what your users are doing.

Comment: i will try this package , i think , it will be useful and quick solution for me , thank you.